# Gradients "backward flow" calculation rulls

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, optimization, gradient-flows, gradient-descent

I am reading article [Hacker's guide to Neural Networks.](http://karpathy.github.io/neuralnets/)
. *Becoming Becoming a Backprop Ninja section*

The quote:

> lets just use variables such as a,b,c,x, and refer to their gradients as da,db,dc,dx respectively. Again, we think of the variables as the “forward flow” and their gradients as “backward flow” along every wire. Our first example was the * gate:

```
x = a * b;
// and given gradient on x (dx), we saw that in backprop we would compute:
da = b * dx;
```

I have rewatched Calculus lectures about derivatives and gradient but still don't understand this simple part.

My reasonings:

The partial derivative of **x** with respect to **a** is equal to **b**.

```
dx/da = b (1)
```

During gradient based optimisation we have **dx** - that is x gradient(vector that points to the maximum and is the sum of partial derivatives vectors). This gradient tells how mutch should we adjust independent variables (that is b here) to get to the maximum.

From (1):

```
da = dx/b
```

So here we need to take gradient of x that came from cost function and divide it into b. Then we can adjust b in that direction.

So why does the author say about `da = b * dx;` and not `da = dx/b` here?
Also if you see some mistakes in my reasoning please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See reverse mode of automatic differentiation for a systematic view.

Think of it as $x$ is the input of another function $f$, $y=f(x)=f(a·b)$ and you want to compute the differential of the combined expression relative to the inputs (also called sensitivities). Then by the chain rule
$$
\frac{∂}{∂a}f(ab)=\frac{∂}{∂x}f(ab)·\frac{∂}{∂a}(ab)=f'(x)·b
$$
That is, the sensitivity $\bar a=\frac{∂f}{∂a}$ is the product of the sensitivity of $x$, $\bar x=\frac{∂f}{∂x}$ times $b$, $$\bar a=b·\bar x.$$

It is better to not call the gradients the same as differentials. One convention is to name them `ba,bx,...`. Then one has

```
bx*dx=ba*da
```

if `b` is constant, or

```
bx*dx=ba*da+bb*db
```

if `b` is also variable. Inserting the product rule for the differentials on the left gives

```
bx*(da*b+a*db) = ba*da+bb*db
```

and by comparing coefficients of `da` and `db` one finds again `ba=bx*b` and `bb=bx*a`.